# to move every single element and value from modal box to input form

Tags: jquery

for start, my english are bad, and i am new to jquery, php, and even html

i have an idea, to show all my data that i get from json and loop it to a card inside a modal box, but now, i gotta select the data and the selected data must move to a fomr input, so i cant post the data that i selected to a database

jquery populated data to card

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({

                type : "POST",
                url : "<?php echo site_url('mainmenu/main/get_data');?>",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {
                    'b_c' : $('#b_c').text(),
                    'c_id' : $('#c_id').text(),
                    's_t' : $('#s_t').val(),
                    's_n': $('[name="s_n"]').val(),
                    't_ye' : $('[name="rer"]').val()
                },
                
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.response_code == 00){
                        let data = response.response_data.data_detail;
                        
                        $.each(data, function (i, arr) {
                            $('#modal-fill').append(`
                                <div class="card mb-2">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">`+ arr.n_i +`</h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">`+ arr.n_asa +`</h6>
                                    <p class="card-text">`+ arr.ala +`</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            `)
                            
                        })
                        $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show');

                    }else{
                        alert(response.response_message)
                        location.reload()
                    }
                }
            })
        })

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Data Anggota</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body modal-dialog-scrollable" id="modal-fill">
              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the form target

```
    <form id="form-target>
      <input type="text" name="n_id">
      <input type="text" name="n_nah">
      <input type="text" name="alat">
    </form>
```

i haavent try anithyng, cuse i don know abut j query before, and i am reading the documentation of jquery while i submit this question
hope you guys understand what i looking for, sory for bad englsih and bad code

Comment: `Select the data..` what do you mean by this ?

Comment: because, the data that shown are more than one, so i must select it first, then move it to form input, so i can add another value before store it to DB

Comment: i see so the user will have to click on card ? If yes show that code as well where you are appending values inside modal .

Comment: i have edited my code, i added the jquery filling code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write click event on `card-link` elements . So ,whenever user click on this element get value of `n_id,alat and n_nah` using `$(this).closest(".card").find(".classname").text()` and then add this values to input-box using `.val()`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose json response look like this :
var response = {
  "response_data": {
    "data_detail": [{
      "n_id": 1,
      "n_nah": "wdw",
      "alat": "dwd"
    }, {
      "n_id": 2,
      "n_nah": "wdw2",
      "alat": "dwd2"
    }]
  }
}

/*$('#button').on('click', function() {
 $.ajax({..
..other codes..*/
let data = response.response_data.data_detail;

$.each(data, function(i, arr) {
  //added class
  $('#modal-fill').append(`<div class="card mb-2"><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title n_id">` + arr.n_id + `</h5><h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted n_nah">` + arr.n_nah + `</h6> 
<p class="card-text alat">` + arr.alat + `</p><a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a><a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a></div></div> `)

})
$('#staticBackdrop').modal('show');

/*}
  })
})*/
//on click of card link..
$("#staticBackdrop").on("click", ".card-link", function() {
  //get closest card
  var selector = $(this).closest(".card")
  //find values and assign them to inputs
  $("input[name='n_id']").val(selector.find(".n_id").text())
  $("input[name='n_nah']").val(selector.find(".n_nah").text())
  $("input[name='alat']").val(selector.find(".alat").text())
  $('#staticBackdrop').modal('hide');

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Data Anggota</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modal-dialog-scrollable" id="modal-fill">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<form id="form-target">
  <input type="text" name="n_id">
  <input type="text" name="n_nah">
  <input type="text" name="alat">
</form>
```

Comment: it consume time to understanding your code, not becuse it bad, because iam bad at code hihi, and i tried to my code woalaa it worked, i vote usefull for your answer. thanks a lot captain

Comment: Hi, go through [Tree traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)  for more info :)

Answer (score 0):

Well. If you just neded to post the data you dont really need to put it in a form.
You can create a FormData object entierely in javascript and post it there.

an example copied from mozilla.org:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to a string "123456"

// HTML file input, chosen by user
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

// JavaScript file-like object
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "[destinationUrl]");
request.send(formData);
```

Comment: the data is incomlete, i must add another value before stored to DB, thats why i need the data in modal box, move to a form iinput